# Linux copy command

Tags: command-line

For example I have two users A and B and A has admin privileges.

I am logged in as B and I want to know how can I copy `/etc/sudoers` in B home directory in a single command and after `/etc/sudoers` is copied it must be owned by B user by default , without using `chmod`, `chown`.

I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: So, you, logged in  as a normal user B, want to copy a file from an Administrators folders A? This shouldn't be allowed in any circumstances as you wouldn't have the necessary permissions to access the other users folders. The other way round is probably different, as the Administrator may have the correct permissions to access user B's files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use `chown` or `chmod`, you can use one of the following methods (in any case you need to have root privileges to read `/etc/sudoers` file):

```
sudo cat /etc/sudoers > ~/sudoers
```

or:

```
touch ~/sudoers
sudo cp /etc/sudoers ~/sudoers
```

In both cases, after `~/sources` file is created, is owned by the current user.

Comment: I never thought about that. Thanks. It is a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

The file `/etc/sudoers` can't be read by other but the `root` user or users with the `root` group.

```
ls -l /etc/sudoers
-r--r-----. 1 root root 669 Jun 28  2012 /etc/sudoers
```

Meaning, that if user B has no administrative privileges, is impossible for him to read (less copy) the `sudoers` files. This is by design, for obvious security reasons, since the hash of the passwords for elevating to `sudo` are there.

For preventing `cp` of preserving the attributes, you can use the `--no-preserve=` switch:

```
sudo cp --no-preserve=ownership /etc/sudoers .
```

The problem with this is that it will take the ownership of the user that is running the command (in this case `root`) so, the ownership will stay the same, but it'll work for other files that don't have the strict permission.

```
$ ls -l /etc/vdpau_wrapper.cfg 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 51 May  5 19:19 /etc/vdpau_wrapper.cfg
$ cp --no-preserve=ownership /etc/vdpau_wrapper.cfg .
$ ls -l vdpau_wrapper.cfg 
-rw-r--r-- 1 braiam braiam 51 Aug 13 09:28 vdpau_wrapper.cfg
```

Comment: Ok, let's say I give B administrative privileges, then I can copy /etc/sudoers in B home directory, but when I type ls -alh it shows me /etc/sudoers is owned by root and I want /etc/sudoers to be owned by B user without using chown

Comment: It must be owned by B user by default after I copy it.

Comment: Your solution is good too. But the following one "sudo cat /etc/sudoers > ~/sudoers" seems to work the best.